# Referirse a un usuario en la ruta de windows

Tags: c#, windows

Necesito saber como referirse en c# a una ruta en el disco, por ejemplo la ruta de la carpeta de dropbox (aplicación cliente), sin necesidad de saber el nombre del usuario.
Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! por favor puedes agregar lo que has intentado / investigado para que los usuarios puedan ayduarte mejor?

Answer (score 1):

DropBox [proporciona](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/locate-dropbox-folder) un archivo `json` (info.json) con la información que buscas. De manera que combinando esta información con la carpeta `LocalAppData` del usuario puedes obtener la ruta completa.

```
var infoPath = @"Dropbox\info.json";
var jsonPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData"), infoPath);            
if (!File.Exists(jsonPath)) jsonPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData"), infoPath);
if (!File.Exists(jsonPath)) throw new Exception("Dropbox could not be found!");
var dropboxPath = File.ReadAllText(jsonPath).Split('\"')[5].Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Si no quieres *parsear* el JSON, puedes recurrir a `JavaScripSerializer`

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();            
var dictionary = (Dictionary < string, object>) serializer.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(jsonPath));
var dropboxPath = (string) ((Dictionary < string, object> )dictionary["personal"])["path"];
```

Respuesta [desde aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660280/how-do-i-programmatically-locate-my-dropbox-folder-using-c)